# How to compute datediff by hour in impala

Tags: impala

How to to compute datediff by hour in impala? For example like below

```
Select datediff(hour,'2017-06-21T02:29:54.244720804Z', '2017-06-21T02:30:10.574379557Z');
```

Default impala 'datediff' function only returns diff by day..

Update:
Solution I figured

```
select cast(abs((unix_timestamp('2017-08-01 01:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') - unix_timestamp('2017-08-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))/3600) as int);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply this workaround,

```
select datediff(time_a, time_b)*24 + hour(time_a) - hour(time_b);
```

Comment: is the not right. For example " datediff('2017-08-16t12:00:00.000000000z', '2017-08-17t10:00:00.000000000z') * 24 + hour('2017-08-16t12:00:00.000000000z') - hour('2017-08-17t10:00:00.000000000z') " => -22, which is correct. But if exchange time_a and time_b: "datediff('2017-08-16t12:00:00.000000000z', '2017-08-17t10:00:00.000000000z') * 24 - hour('2017-08-16t12:00:00.000000000z') + hour('2017-08-17t10:00:00.000000000z')" => -26. it is wrong

Comment: huh? isn't -22 correct?   do you want time_b - time_a ? just reverse them both.  `select datediff('2017-08-17t10:00:00.000000000z', '2017-08-16t12:00:00.000000000z') * 24 - hour('2017-08-16t12:00:00.000000000z') + hour('2017-08-17t10:00:00.000000000z');`

Comment: -22 is correct ;p but after switch time_a and time_b, the result is -26. See my comment above

Comment: you need to switch both .  either `select datediff(time_a, time_b)*24 + hour(time_a) - hour(time_b);`  or `select datediff(time_b, time_a)*24 + hour(time_b) - hour(time_a);`